# Spring boot @WebFilter by specific urlPatterns does not work

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, filter

I have `SpringBootApplication`:

```
@ServletComponentScan
@SpringBootApplication
public class ExampleApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
```

Properties file contains:

```
server.contextPath=/example
```

And filter:

```
@WebFilter(urlPatterns = { "/example/*" })
public class AuthorizationFilter implements Filter {
```

When I execute REST method `GET /example/test`:

```
@RestController
public class ExampleController {

    @GetMapping("/test")
    public String getTest(){
```

`WebFilter` does not catch it.

But if I change to:

```
@WebFilter(urlPatterns = { "/*" })
public class AuthorizationFilter implements Filter {
```

WebFilter catches all requests.

If I add `@Component`:

```
@Component
@WebFilter(urlPatterns = { "/example/*" })
public class AuthorizationFilter implements Filter {
```

During startup I get:

```
st-startStop-38] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'authorizationFilter' to: [/*]
```

Why does it happen? How to filter by specific (context) path?